# What is “Protocol Capability Request” and how to resolve?

Tags: ios, iphone, cdma

I try to activate an Apple iPhone 4 CDMA but my carrier says:

> As per our technical team confirmation received, the device is not able to send the MEID in response to "Protocol Capability Request" message requested by OTAF during *228 call, might be the device is not supporting MEID and is supported only ESN (Old 8 digit). Though the MEID/pESN is written on the device but in actual it is ESN based device, as this is an open market device.

I don't know what I have to do now. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have done something to the phone to prevent it from sending the MEID, there is nothing else to do. The device is apparently simply not capable of doing what the carrier requires for activation.

Comment: is there any process to solve the same like i have to reset my device oe anything else because it is Jail breaked